# How do I pass checkbox collection values in a controller spec with rspec and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rspec, parameter-passing

With rails 3 and rspec. I have a form in a view like this ..

```
<%= form_for current_account, { :url => admins_account_path(current_account), :method => 'put' } do %>
  <div class="action">
    <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>

      <% @accountships.each do |accountship| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag "accountship_ids[]", accountship.id, accountship.admin? %></td>
          <td><%= accountship.user.name %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>

    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller, I handle the PUT with this method in accounts#update_admin. This is all working as expected.

```
@account.assign_administrators params[:accountship_ids]
```

My question is how do I construct the parameters in rspec to test that controller action. What I have tried so far is not working. Here's my latest try that doesn't work.

```
before(:each) do
  # code that generates the ids, I know this is working from other tests ..
  .
  .
  .
  @attr = {
    :accountship_ids => [
      @admin_accountship.id,
      @not_admin_accountship.id,
      @signed_in_user_accountship.id
    ]
  }
end

it "should assign admin to users in the list" do

  # what should I be passing in as @attr?
  put :update_admins, :id => @account, :accountship_ids => @attr  

  Accountship.find(@admin_accountship.id).admin.should be_true
  Accountship.find(@owner_accountship.id).admin.should be_true
  Accountship.find(@not_admin_accountship.id).admin.should_not be_true
end
```

All the tests I've been able to write that require values from the form checkbox collection are failing, and it's apparent that the whatever_accountship.admin attribute is not being updated when the rspec test is posting the data.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I stumbled onto the solution. The array shouldn't have been wrapped in a hash, and the values in the array literal needed to be converted to strings first, as below.

```
 @attr = [
   @admin_accountship.id.to_s,
   @not_admin_accountship.id.to_s,
   @signed_in_user_accountship.id.to_s
 ]
```

Anyone understand why they need to be strings when other tests I have can accept a full-blown object (no strings required)?

Also, what do I do to my question now that I know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning the params hash to an instance variable and then making a new hash with the first hash as the value and passing the whole mess in the `put` statement, when all you need to do is pass the original params. Or in other words:

`put :update_admins, :id => @account.id, @attr`

**EDIT**

Sorry, long day. The params need to go into a single hash following the action, so:

`put :update_admins, {:id=>@account.id}.merge(@attr)`

**EDIT 2**

The hash syntax will work if you pass strings in the array:

```
@attr = {
  :accountship_ids => [
    @admin_accountship.id.to_s,
    @not_admin_accountship.id.to_s,
    @signed_in_user_accountship.id.to_s
  ]
}
```

If you want to resolve the question with your own answer, I think you can just create an answer and then accept it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. The way you've stated it wont't run and throws this error => syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC. If I reverse the last two params (put @attr first, doesn't seem right) then the test runs but fails with => no route matches {:accountship_ids=>[1,3,2], :controller=>"accounts", :action=>"update_admins"}. Just passing those ids as an array like this .. :accountship_ids => [3,2,1] gives me the same result as the original code I posted. Test fails, no records are actually updated by the spec.

Comment: Your change still errors out, but I've found the solution. I construct @attr as an array literal (not wrapped in curly brackets). If I call .to_s on the id values in the array before passing it, the tests will pass! Anyone know why I have to pass an array of strings into the controller? In other cases I can pass full object with attributes into params hash, no conversion to string necessary?